# C++ контейнерный класс stack

Tags: c++, стек

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T> class node
{
public:
    T* data;
    node<T>* tail;
    node() {
        tail = NULL;
    }
};

template<class T> class stack
{
private:
    node<T>* header;

public:
    stack()
    {
        header = NULL;
    }

    void push(T& obj)
    {
        node<T>* n = new node<T>();
        n->tail = header;
        n->data = &obj;
        header = n;
    }


    T pop()
    {
        if (!empty())
        {
           return -1;
        }
            int temp = header-> tail;
            node <T>* = header;
            header = header->data;
            return temp;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return header == NULL;
    }
};


class student
{
public:
    char name[64];
    char code[32];
    int bithday;
    student()
    { }
    student(char* n, char* c, int  b)
    {
        strcpy(name, n);
        strcpy(code, c);
        bithday = b;
    }
};


int main()
{
    student s1("Ivan", "0001", 2001);
    student s2("Pert", "0002", 2002);
    student s3("Gleb", "0003", 2000);

    stack<student> s;
    s.push(s1);
    s.push(s2);
    s.push(s3);

    while (!s.empty())
    {
        student tmp = s.pop();
        cout << tmp.name << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

не могу понять как реализовать удаление элементов в контейнере класса

Comment: Функция   pop()  возвращает  только -1

Comment: немного но у меня почему-то не запускается перерыл весь интернет толковой информации не нашел

Comment: `pop()` проще переделать с нуля, чем исправлять. Неужели не получилось нагуглить готовую реализацию?

Comment: У вас опечатка в условии `if (!empty())`. Уберите отрицание (восклицательный знак): `if (empty())`. А то сейчас вы пытаетесь извлекать элементы из пустого стека и сдаётесь при их наличии, а надо наоборот.

Comment: @Arhad, по вашему ошибка только в этом?...

Comment: // функция удаления элемента из стека
template <typename T>
inline T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    // проверяем размер стека
    assert(top > 0); // номер текущего элемента должен быть больше 0
 
    stackPtr[--top]; // удаляем элемент из стека
}
нашел такую реализацю, но она не совсем похожа

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, нет, конечно. Утечка памяти "удалённого" узла из-за отсутствующего `delete`, непонятная конструкция `node <T>* = header;` с отсутствующим именем переменной и `header = header->data;` (как? зачем вытаскивать полезную нагрузку узла и пытаться поместить её в качестве указателя на сам узел?) пусть останутся для других участников.

Comment: Угу, а еще `int temp = header-> tail;` попытка засунуть указатель в `int`, а потом вернуть этот `int`, хотя возвращаемый тип - `T`.

Comment: @igor96 А вы вместо "удаление элемента из стека" ищите "удаление элемента из связного списка".

Answer (score 0):

```
int pop()
{
    if (!empty())
    {
        node <T>* p = header;
        header = header->tail;
        delete p;
        return 1;
    }  
    return 0;   
}
```

хотябы так, если хотите возвращать `int` а не `bool`, хотя возвращать ничего не нужно, вприципе  это значение не будет использоваться, или будете использовать вместо `empty()`, тогда  функция `empty()` не нужна

P.S.
Но вы еще и  имена неправильно используете,  Хвост у вас предыдущий, а  голова является хвостом...